# Accessing object in template

Tags: json, object, ember.js

I am working on an Ember project. I have :

1. Route named 'states'
2. Template 'states'
3. StatesController extending Ember.ObjectController
4. StatesRoute that returns a model using

   ```
   Ember.$.getJSON(url);
   ```

The data from this url returns a JSON object similar to :

```
{
   "locations":[...],
   "stores":[....]
}
```

How do I access this JSON from the template. Since the data is a JSON object, I have to use ObjectController. But how do I get the object itself?

I have tried {{#with}}, {{#with controller}}, {{#with content}} {{#with content.locations}}, {{#with model}} with no errors or data each time. I am currently out of ideas as I am new to Ember. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: try {{#each model.locations}}{{this.`someproperty in location`}}{{/each}}

Comment: Your line worked, probably. But console informs me that CORS was blocked. I don't understand why this error wasn't raised before. Any idea how I could solve this issue?

Comment: I am working to make the getJSON work. Once I get it working, I'll try your solution.

Comment: are you serving ember app from server or from file system?

Comment: @Hardik127 File system

Comment: I have successfully solved CORS. But the template is loaded with nothing in {{each}} rendered. I suspect that this is because my model returns async

Comment: @Hardik127 Your method worked. Consider posting it as an answer that I may accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a `$.getJSON(url)` call in the model hook of your route, ember will set model property of that route's controller as the reply from your request. So `model.locations` will give location array. If you want to use 'locations' instead of 'model.locations' use `ObjectController` as your controller.

Using the following in your template will fix your problem:-

```
{{#each model.locations}}
   {{this.somePropertyOfLOcation}}
{{/each}}
```